# Is there any way to overwrite Zend_Validate::is() in Magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, zend-validate

I need to change the validation method for emails, so I was wondering if regular Magento overwriting rules extend to Zend's validaton function: `Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')`. What's the best to overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your [own validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html), and pass it to `Zend_Validate::is()` method.

Use `Zend_Validate::addDefaultNamespaces()` if you use a different namespace (ie: `My_`)

```
Zend_Validate:is($email, 'My_Validator_EmailAddress');
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
$customValidator = new My_Validator_EmailAddress();
$isValid = $customaValidator->isValid($email);
```

Comment: I see, so I would have to modify either parameter to the function, or the call. There is no way to keep the line of code: Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress') the same?

Comment: Except editing the core file of the Validator, no.
You may try to remove default namespace, add you own, and use the same name. Take a look at the source code of Zend_Validate::is() it'll show you how the class are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can override this class by adding new file to local code pool: **app/code/local/Zend/Validate.php**
But in this case you should copy all methods from the original class.